# Increase Thingsboard speed

Tags: performance, thingsboard

I'm working on an IoT project that involves a sensor transmitting its values to Thingsboard platform.

I made the installation on an Ubuntu machine that has 8Gb of RAM available but still, Thingsboard is running too slow. Therefore, I studied the CPU load and RAM usage. Basically, my results show that Cassandra is consuming 29,5% of memory and Thingsboard 9,9% and 7,6% (two entries in the 'top' utility); which means a total of 2,36+1,4 = 3,76Gb.

I followed the instructions in the installation guide, section 'Memory update for slow machines' to see the effect of reducing Cassandra consumption of resources (results: Cassandra consumes now 5% of memory) but then again no improvements noticed.

Is there something I can do to make it run faster? It is really impossible to work correctly with this slowness...

Comment: Please specify your performance load profile. What tasks are you executing and how you measure slowness?
Also, we support near 2M records per minute speed on normal env: https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/performance/

Comment: Please post this as an answer :-) Some people don't read comments and will just think that thingsboard is slow..

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough on my last post. I wasn't talking about performance in terms of data collection or processing of the incoming messages. I was talking about the Web interface of Thingsboard. I was actually running the application using a browser on the same machine that was running thingsboard and Cassandra. Due to the consumption of resources that both imply, the Web interface was very slow in terms of time of reponse... I tried using another machine to work on the Web interface and it was actually much better.. My bad!

Comment: How did you deploy the web part only in another machine? Mind sharing some links on the process or resources you consulted please?